# xlabel, ylabel not working. 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to give my axis labels but they wont show up because of a syntax error. This is my code.

```
file = 'SAW data omgekeerd goed.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ';', parse_dates= True, index_col = 0, dayfirst = True)

plt.plot(data['0.005 (B4.01) Studielandschap'])
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

> File "C:/Users/steven/Documents/BIM/Minor Data Science/Outlier
>   detection SAW/Anomaly detection 0.1.py", line 24, in 
>   plt.xlabel('Month') TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: What is the _full_ error?

Comment: I may have edited out the syntax error by mistake... There was an apostrophe after `plt.xlabel('Month')'`. This may be the cause so I have put it back in until OP clarifies.

Comment: The error:

  File "C:/Users/steven/Documents/BIM/Minor Data Science/Outlier detection SAW/Anomaly detection 0.1.py", line 24, in <module>
    plt.xlabel('Month')


TypeError: 'str' object is not callable


I deleted the apostrophe now it gives a different error. Plt does work for creating the plot.

Comment: Restarted spyder and it is functioning. should have done that first, I am pretty new to coding. sorry

Answer (score 20):

Did you do `plt.xlabel='month'` before this?
Which would result in altering of the imported function, causing the typeError.
Restart and run, should be fine.

Edit: If due to some reason you don't want to restart. 
You can reload the module by

```
from importlib import reload
matplotlib=reload(matplotlib)
```

Use imp instead of importlib if it's not 3.4+

Answer (score 2):

This problem usually occurs if the import function is being altered.
If we use `plt.ylabel='test'` in place of `plt.ylabel('test')`, then it may alter the import.

To resolve this just restart the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

**If you try to do this**

```
    plt.xlabel = "Label"
    plt.ylabel = "Label"
```

**And also this**

```
    plt.xlabel("Label")
    plt.ylabel("Label")
```

**And still not working Then Try This**

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from importlib import reload
    plt=reload(plt)
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use

```
plt.xlabel = "something"
```

so you have the problem with me.

I use `anaconada-jupyter`, my solution is:

1. Click "run" - click "Restart Kernel and Run All Cells..."

[image]

Then, the problem will be gone because you restarted the kernel.